# Understanding WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObject

Tags: c++, createprocess

I have a windows service where I am receiving http requests and launching a process for it which might run more than an hour . I need to get notified in main service when a process ends .And when service is ended i need to terminate all child processes . I understand that if I do waitforsingleobject it will hang on windows service until the process is completed , and no further http requests will be entertained ? I am doing following for now which works but its not correct approach .

```
if(CreateProcess( TEXT(EXEPATH),   
                procArguments, 
                NULL,          
                NULL,          
                FALSE,         
                0,             
                NULL,          
                NULL,          
                &si,           
                &pi )          
            ) 
            {
                 processHandles[processCount] = pi.hProcess;                 
                 processStreams[processCount] = eventId.c_str();                    
                 processCount++;                 
             }
```

On Service stop I am doing this

```
for(int index=0;index<10;index++){
            g_pAppLog->Log("Stop Process for processStreams[%d] %s\n",index,processStreams[index].c_str());

            int terminationResult = TerminateProcess(processHandles[index],1);                  

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028(v=vs.85).aspx) allow you to specify a timeout, so that the function will not hang forever.

You can thus call the function in a loop, checking if the process has really terminated, or it's just a timeout expiration.

Anyway, you should not WaitFor anything, unless you have nothing better to do.
If you have a web server, you should listen to connection and spawn responding processes.
If you just want to check if a process terminated, you can call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx).

So, summing up, you might either:

1. Run a loop that:

   1. accepts a request;
   2. spawns a process;
   3. checks if any of the previously created process terminated (without blocking);
2. Make a two-thread application, with one thread accepting requests, and the other one calling `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` in a loop, and possibly handling children termination.

Answer (score 0):

In your main service, you should create a thread to do that, so the main thread can still be running.. In this thread, you should use WaitforMultipleObjects to wait for all the child process to end, once a process is ended, the corresponding code will be execute.

Please check the  MSDN for details

Answer (score 0):

Do the waiting in a different thread than the one that is processing SCM requests.  Use `CreateEvent()` to create a waitable manual-reset event, then have the waiting thread use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait on both the event and the child process at the same time.  `WaitForMultipleObjects()` will tell you which one is signaled first.  When the service is being stopped, signal the event with `SetEvent()`.  When the child process exits, its handle will be signaled. If the event gets signaled first, the waiting thread can call `TerminateProcess()` on the child process.